# React Native Circle Image on Android

Tags: android, image, reactjs, react-native

I am simply trying to take a square image and contain it within a circle in my react-native app on Android.  A circle image basically.

```
<View style={mainStyle.profileImageContainer}>
            <Image
              style={mainStyle.profileImage}
              source={{uri: CONFIG.media_url+this.props.image}} 
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
</View>
```

and styles:

```
profileImageContainer: {
    translateY: -43,
    alignSelf: 'center',
},
profileImage: {
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    height: 86,
    width: 86,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 75,
    overlayColor: CREAM,
},
```

But the only way to get it remotely circular on Android is to add the "overlayColor", but I need this to be transparent so the design behind is visible.  The property transparent does not work.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?  Am I missing some sort of simple property?

EDIT: Thanks to Dhruv Parmar's answer, I realised the issue is because I was using a GIF image.  The method you would expect seems to work fine with jpgs and pngs, but not GIFS!

Comment: Can you show how your image is currently displaying ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have a wrapping view to achieve this, simply using `borderRadius` set to half of image size should do the trick. Any other styles you want can be applied directly to `Image` view

You can see an example here https://snack.expo.io/rJI4DzoDW

Answer (score 4):

> Use this style;

```
image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 150 / 2,
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "red"
  }
```